# Remove line break from string not working

Tags: java

I'm attempting to remove a carriage return from a java string, but not having much luck so far.  Here's what I currently have code wise.  You can have a look at the desired strings needed below compared to what I'm getting.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String tempString = "";
    String tempStringTwo = "";
    String [] convertedLines = new String [100];
    int counter = 0;
    int tempcount = 0;

    File file = new File("input.txt");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        System.out.println(args[0] + " does not exist.");
    return;
    }
    if (!(file.isFile() && file.canRead())) {
        System.out.println(file.getName() + " cannot be read from.");
    return;
    }
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        char current;

        while (fis.available() > 0) { // Filesystem still available to read bytes from file
            current = (char) fis.read();
            tempString = tempString + current;
            int character = (int) current;
            if (character==13) { // found a line break in the file, need to ignore it.
                //tempString = tempString.replace("\n"," ").replace("\r"," ");
                tempString = tempString.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", " ");
                //tempString = tempString.substring(0,tempString.length()-1);
                //System.out.println(tempString);
            }
            if (character==46) { // found a period
                //System.out.println("Found a period.");
                convertedLines[counter] = tempString;
                tempString = "";
                counter++;
                tempcount = counter;
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
    for (int z=0;z<tempcount;z++){
        System.out.println(convertedLines[z]);
    }    
}
```

Here's my current output...

```
The quick brown fox 
jumps over the lazy dogs.
Now is the  time for all good men to come to the 
aid of their country.
All your base are 
belong to us.
```

Here's what I need...

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.
All your base are belong to us.
```

Comment: Note: don't check `fis.available() > 0` to detect EOF. Check the int value of `fis.read()`, and break if it is `< 0`.

Comment: Also: no need to cast `current` to assign it to `character`; and no need for `character`, as you can just use `current` directly; and no need to use `13` and `46`, use `'\r'` and `'.'` instead.

Comment: Why bother checking for `13`? Why not just `convertedLines[counter] = tempString.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", " ");` in the "found a period" block?

Comment: `available() == 0` is *not* an indication of end of stream. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

Processing one character at a time is probably the simplest way to handle this problem.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class SentencePerLiner {
  public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
    for (;;) {
      int ch = System.in.read();
      switch (ch) {
      case '.':
        System.out.println('.');
        break;
      case '\n':
      case '\r':
        break;
      default:
        if (ch < 0) return;
        System.out.print((char) ch);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```